# How do I set streetView in my mapview

Tags: android, google-maps

I an working on an android project whereby i need to set my map to zoom in and show a more detailed view of my map, like the streets of where i want my coordinates to triangulate. The problem is in Mapview class, setStreetView is deprecated, wat is the alternative?
This is how setStreetView looks when i use it.

```
package com.HelloMapView;

import java.util.List;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class HelloMapView extends MapActivity {
    MapView mapview;
    LinearLayout linearlayout;
    List<Overlay> mapOverlay;
    Drawable drawable;
    HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mapview=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapview.setStreetView(true);
        mapOverlay=mapview.getOverlays();
        drawable=this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker);
        itemizedOverlay=new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable);
        GeoPoint geoPoint=new GeoPoint(19240000,-99120000);
        OverlayItem overlayitem=new OverlayItem(geoPoint,"","");
        itemizedOverlay.addoverlay(overlayitem);
        mapOverlay.add(itemizedOverlay);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

this does not work it only shows square boxes with no map at all

Answer (score 0):

Use **setStreetView(boolean)** of MapView.

Comment: setStreetView(boolean)is DEPRECATED. on Google API 11

Comment: you can use mapView.setSatellite(true); also.

Answer (score 0):

```
myMapView.setStreetView(true);
```

Comment: this method is marked as **DEPRECATED as off SDK Level 11**

Answer (score 0):

public class ABC extends MapActivity {

```
private static MapController myMapController = null;
private static GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint
```

(
            (int) (25.24243399999999 * 1E6), (int) (55.30611937301637 * 1E6));

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.contact_us_layout);

    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.displayZoomControls(false);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setFocusable(true);
    myMapController = mapView.getController();
    myMapController.animateTo(geoPoint);
    myMapController.setZoom(15);
    // mapView.invalidate();
    // mapView.setFocusable(true);
    myMapController.setCenter(geoPoint);
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.mapmarker);
    HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(
            drawable, this);

    OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint,
            "abc");

    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);


    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

    //mapView.setSatellite(true);
    **mapView.setStreetView(true);**
```

public class HelloItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {
        private ArrayList mOverlays = new ArrayList();
        private Context mContext;

```
    public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        mOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return mOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return mOverlays.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
        OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
        dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
        dialog.show();
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Hello,,, 
I have posted the working code for what u desire...
If your map isn't displaying anything. Your api key is not signed properly..Please sign it again and provide it in mapView. 
If you want streetView of map use:
mapView.setStreetView(true)
If you want satelliteView of map use:
mapView.setSatellite(true)

Comment: My emulator cannot connect to the internet, could this be the problem because your code is not working and setStreetView is said to be DEPRECATED in eclipse Google API 11.